# Make Nav Menu Responsive

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make my page's nav menu responsive. Currently, icons don't fit on the screen as the height is decreased. Ideally what I'm wanting is a responsive design where all of the elements scale with the page height (ie, icons and text shrinks to fit).

So far, I can only get the design to work with hard-coded values as below. This requires multiple breakpoints which I'm trying to avoid as getting everything to fit just right with hard coded values is proving too lengthy a process.

https://jsfiddle.net/froggomad/392qje0o/

```css
.topnav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.topnav #myLinks {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 15%;
  height: 85vh;
  width: 400px;
  margin-left: 80%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 10px;
  bottom: 5%;
}

.menu-link {
  padding-top: 0.5em;
}

.menu-card {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 18%;
}

.menu-card:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  opacity: 100%;
  transition: all 0.8s;
}


/*Transforms .card-text when hovering on .menu-card*/

.menu-card:hover .card-text {
  opacity: 100;
  max-width: 66%;
  /*this is the attribute being animated in .card-text*/
  width: 38%;
  /*sets actual width*/
  background-color: rgba(148, 181, 201, 0.9);
  border-width: 8px;
}

.menu-icon {
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: -265px;
  margin-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  max-width: 20%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: rgba(148, 181, 201, 0.9);
  border-radius: 90px;
  padding: 8px;
}

.card-text {
  max-width: 0%;
  opacity: 0;
  color: #5DCA31;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
  float: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 22%;
  padding: 0.5em;
  padding-right: 140px;
  padding-left: 2%;
  padding-top: 24px;
  padding-bottom: 35px;
  border-color: rgba(148, 181, 201, 0.9);
  border-width: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 90px;
  transition: background-color 0.8s, border-width 0.8s, max-width 0.8s;
}

#home {
  /*Text*/
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-top: 3%;
}

.home {
  /*Icon*/
  margin-top: 3%;
}

#strategy {
  font-size: 1.25em;
}

#security {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

#pledge {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <div class="top-bar">
    <a href="#" id="site-title">
                   Site Title
              </a>
  </div>
  <!-- Navigation links (hidden by default) -->
  <div id="myLinks" class="menu-link">
    <div class="menu-card">
      <a href="#">
        <img class="menu-icon home" src="https://www.shareicon.net/data/128x128/2015/09/22/104866_home_512x512.png">
        <p class="card-text" id="home">Home</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-card">
      <a href="#">
        <img class="menu-icon" src="https://www.shareicon.net/data/128x128/2015/09/21/104860_find_512x512.png">
        <p class="card-text" id="strategy">Current Strategy</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-card">
      <a href="#">
        <img class="menu-icon" src="https://www.shareicon.net/data/128x128/2015/09/22/104877_locked_512x512.png">
        <p class="card-text" id="security">Security</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-card">
      <a href="#">
        <img class="menu-icon" src="https://www.shareicon.net/data/128x128/2015/09/22/104870_users_512x512.png">
        <p class="card-text" id="pledge">Pledge!</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <!--End Navigation links-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you are familiar with CSS Flexbox Layout. Then flex-shrink will help to shrink both text and icons in order to fit in the screen.
You can [visit](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)! this link to know more about Flexbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working version using flexbox and position absolute.

https://jsfiddle.net/my6nwu0e/

```
.top-bar {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.topnav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
}

.topnav #myLinks {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: fixed;
  width: 300px;
  top: 10%;
  right: 0;
  height: 85vh;
  max-height: 85%;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.menu-link {
  padding-top: 0.5em;
}

.menu-card {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 1 1 25%;
}

.menu-card a {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu-icon {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  right: 20%;
  max-height: 65%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(148, 181, 201, 0.9);
  transition: all 0.8s;
}

.card-text {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 0;
  top: 6%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 0;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  color: #5DCA31;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
  margin: 0;
  border-color: rgba(148, 181, 201, 0.9);
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 90px;
  transition: all 0.8s;
}

.menu-card:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.8s;
}

.menu-card:hover .menu-icon {
  right: 0;
}

.menu-card:hover .card-text {
  opacity: 1;
  padding-left: 10%;
  max-height: 65%;
  width: 100%;
  border-width: 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: rgba(148, 181, 201, 0.9);
}

@media screen and (max-height: 700px) {
  .topnav #myLinks {
    width: 200px;
  }
}
```

You were using too many margin properties, and seemed like there were a lot of unnecessary/redundant styles, although maybe they depended on the other styles in the page that you did not post. You will have to change the the width of `#myLinks` using media query, but other than that I think this is a pretty responsive solution. Also consider using `box-sizing: border-box` as a global style.